# Angular JS broadcast msg to multiple views including a modal window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a service that is used to handle message broadcasting to controllers that need it.

service:

```
.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
  var sharedService = {};

  sharedService.message = '';

  sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(msg) {
    this.message = msg;
    this.broadcastItem();
  };

  sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
  };
  return sharedService;
});
```

cntl:

```
function AlertCtrl($scope, mySharedService) {
  $scope.msgs = [];
  $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
    $scope.msgs.push(mySharedService.message);
  });  
  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.msgs.splice(index, 1);
  };
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="AlertCtrl">
  <alert ng-repeat="msg in msgs" type="msg.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{msg.msg}}</alert>
</div>
```

so any where I drop the HTML snippet the message is displayed as expected, EXCEPT if it is in a modal window.

my question is: How do I get the broadcasted message to display in the modal window?

Here is the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/l6ohBYRBMftpfxiKXvLr?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one instance of `AlertCtrl` in the main page and another instance is created whenever the modal opens (add console.log to verify this). The `AlertCtrl` inside the model gets instantiated and starts listening *after* the event has been broadcasted.

Comment: hmmmmmm, so how do i get the message set in the modal if the modal fires after the message is broadcasted?

Comment: Have the msgs list in the ModalDemoCtrl and pass it to the modal (like you do with items). Whenever a new message is pushed to the list (e.g by an async task), it will be displayed in the modal, provided it is open (otherwise it would not even exist).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to $broadcast method, so you could do:
`$rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast', 'your message here');`

and in your listener:

```
$scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function(ev, arg){
    $scope.msgs.push(msg);
});
```

Have a look: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$broadcast

Comment: the broadcast is already working. my question is why does it not work if it is nested in the modal?